# How to avoid reactjs to be included twice in a rails and reactjs environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, tcomb

I am using react-rails and browserify. In the application.js I use

```
// require react
// require react-ujs
```

Also I use tcomb-form by using

```
var t=require("tcomb-form")
```

As the result I saw reactjs is included twice in my asset pipeline.

How should I correctly use reactjs with rails?

EDIT:

by the way, if you see this error in your console, probably you are having the same issue with reactjs got included twice.

```
[Error] Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's render method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that react was being referenced twice in

```
app/assets/javascripts/server_rendering.js
```

When I removed the line

```
//= require react-server
```

it fixed my issues and got rid of the addComponentAsRefTo() error.
Please bear in mind that I have not tried to deploy the app yet, but this worked for getting it to crud.

Answer (score 0):

by the way, the workaround I came up with is to remove the following from application.js

```
// require react
// require react-ujs
```

and just copy and paste the source code for react-ujs in application.js and use

```
var React = require("react");
```

I know it is not elegant, if you have any better suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
//= require_self
//= require react_ujs

global.React = require('react');
```

This is how I'm using react with Browserify & Rails.  Sets us up for testing as well.

Comment: i will try, so your way react_ujs doesn't complain about not being able to find React?

Comment: sorry it doesn't work, unless you declare React as a global variable. otherwise react_ujs will complain it cannot find React. 

    Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Comment: Aye.  I mis-typed it, should've gone on the global scope.  Fixed above.  Another way I've been trying to get server side rendering to work is to precompile / browserify and require the bundle above react_ujs.  Still working on that and setting up Mocha tests.